# image not being displayed from sqlite db field

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having trouble retrieving the path to my image on my sd on an app that I'm working on. 
I've tried using the setImageDrawable method as well as the setImageURI method and neither 
seems to display the picture on my sdcard. The database field for the picpath is a string 
field that just points to the file on my sd card. I get a runtime standard runtime exception 
error in my stack trace. Code is as follows:

```
public void DisplayAllStudents(){

         //File f = new File("/sdcard/studentpics/gntamT.jpg");

         DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

         db.open();

         Cursor c = db.getAllStudents();

         if(c.moveToFirst()){

             do{

                 stuID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_ROWID));
                 stuName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_STUDENTNAME));
                 stuDOB = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_DOB));
                 stuAddress1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_ADDRESS1));
                 stuAddress2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_ADDRESS2));
                 stuTown = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_TOWN));
                 stuPostcode = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_POSTCODE));
                 stuPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_PHONE));
                 stuPicPath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_PIC_PATH));

                 //add database values to ArrayList
                 results.add(" " + Html.fromHtml(stuName.toString() + "<br>" + stuDOB + "<br>" + stuAddress1 + "<br>" + stuAddress2 + "<br>" + stuTown + "<br>" + stuPostcode + "<br>" + stuPhone));

                 //add fields to our second array list so that we can
                 //pass ALL of the fields to the student details screen
                 dataList.add(stuID.toString() + "," + stuName.toString() + "," + stuDOB.toString() + "," + stuAddress1.toString() + "," + stuAddress2.toString() + "," + stuTown.toString() + "," + stuPhone.toString());


                 ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.studenticon);
                 imgView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(strPathToPic));


                 //display record
                 //DisplayStudent(c);
             }while(c.moveToNext());
         }
        //bind data to list view
         list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(StudentTrackerActivity.this,R.layout.datalayout,R.id.txtFname,results));



        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long id) {

               try{


                String item = list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


                Intent intent = new Intent(StudentTrackerActivity.this,StudentDetails.class);

                //pass values from list view to student details 
                //screen 
                Bundle b = new Bundle(); 
                b.putString("stDetails", item);

                intent.putExtras(b);

                startActivity(intent);


               }catch(IllegalStateException ex){

                   ex.printStackTrace();
               }

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





            }
        });

         db.close();
    }
```

String path to picture:

```
strPathToPic = dir.toString() + "/" + txtStudentName.getText().toString().trim() + ".jpg";
```

Stack trace:

```
Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2496  
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2512   
    ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 119 
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1863  
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4363    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 860  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 618 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not draw image direct so use this method and draw image

```
    Drawable drawable_from_url(String url, String src_name) throws java.net.MalformedURLException, java.io.IOException 
{
    return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream)new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), src_name);
}
```

Comment: What do I need to put in the src_name argument?

Comment: @user615099 simple url value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap photobitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strPathToPic);
imageView.setImageBitmap(photobitmap);
```

Comment: check strPathtoPic, it should be file path not file uri